# Does permutation permute also dependence?

Tags: multivariate-analysis, joint-distribution, independence, randomness

I have a random vector $X = (X_1, \ldots, X_n)$ jointly distributed in someway, assuming also some mutual dependence between its marginal variables.

If I apply a permutation to the vectors drawn from such distribution, rearranging coordinates, is dependence structure simply permuted as well, or is it lost?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The dependence structure is simply the values of $f(x_1,\cdots,x_n):=P(X_1,\cdots,X_n)$. So by permuting the vectors, you are also permuting the dependence. Nothing is lost (unless you can't keep track of your permutation indices). For example, if $Y=(Y_1,\cdots,Y_n)$ with $Y_i=X_{\pi(i)}$, where $\pi$ is your permutation, then $P(Y_1,\cdots,Y_n)=f(Y_{\pi^{-1}(1)},Y_{\pi^{-1}(2)},\cdots,Y_{\pi^{-1}(n)})=P(X_1,...,X_n)$.

Comment: Well, sorry for interruption but, Alex, in the last part, you mentioned if $Y = (Y_1, ..., Y_n)$ with $Y_i = X_{\pi(i)}$, then
$$P(Y_1, ......, Y_n) = f(Y_{\pi(1)}, Y_{\pi(2)},......Y_{\pi(n)})$$ Is this statement true or should be modified as $$P(Y_1, ......, Y_n) = f(X_{\pi(1)}, X_{\pi(2)},......X_{\pi(n)})$$ instead?? In addition, now suppose $X = (X_1, ......, X_n)$ is a sequence of n independent random variables, then how could we prove that if the permutation $\pi$ is independent of X, then $$Z = (X_{\pi(1)}, X_{\pi(2)}, ...... X_{\pi(n)})$$
are independent????

Comment: @son520804: Looks like I dropped an inverse, corrected. Thanks!

Comment: @son520804: Independence is $P(\cap_i X_i)=\prod_i P(X_i)$, i.e. intersections, which are commutative and associative: $X_1\cap X_2\cap X_3=X_{\pi(1)}\cap X_{\pi(2)}\cap X_{\pi(3)}$.

Comment: This isn't really a valid argument: you merely assert the equality of "$P$" (whatever that might be--presumably it is some sort of description of the distribution).  A valid argument would, at a minimum, invoke some definition of "dependence structure" (or another characterization equivalent to that definition) and use that to formulate and demonstrate the result.

Comment: Thanks Alex. It makes much sense since using the bijective property of permutation can prove the independence. But I am also wondering whether there are some cases that the permutation, say, $\pi$, is dependent on the $X_i$'s. Are there any or there is not?